# New Firefox Update Menu Bookmark padding spacing fix?

Tags: user-interface, firefox, updates

Recently (about an hour ago) my firefox auto updated to a new format, where all the text and bookmarks are forcibly spaced as if I were writing a double spaced essay. This has cut down the maximum number of displayed icons severely in book marks and there's what feels like a quarter inch of extra useless grey space in my top browser between the menu/file/edit/view/etc. section and the tabs.

Is there a way, such as through about:config to fix this vertical/height spacing issue of the UI?

I have been unsuccessful in locating a fix.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack OverFlow. I have asked a similar question in the SuperUser Forum. Feel free to comment and add your own experiences. https://superuser.com/questions/1654597/firefox-menus-became-double-spaced-in-latest-update-i-want-to-return-to-single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try browser.proton.contextmenus.enabled > false (disables Proton UI of context menus)

from https://www.ghacks.net/2021/06/01/firefox-89-ships-with-interface-changes/

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. I tried the other workaround using a chrome folder and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to me. This worked (from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1186601):

- Find the latest profile that FF just created. Mine was in "C:\Users\(my_name)\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles". Look for the newest folder, go into it and find the folder called 'chrome'
- Open userChrome.css in Notepad.
- Paste this at the bottom of the file:

```
/* Use Normal top and bottom padding for Compact */
#PlacesToolbarItems .bookmark-item {
  padding-top: 2px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

- Save the file and restart FF.

I changed the padding to 0px and it looks great.

Comment: I don't have a Chrome folder.

Comment: In most cases, the chrome folder isn't automatically created for you. You can simply create the folder yourself and then create the file "userChrome.css" in there.

Comment: It did not worked for me.

Comment: For me this worked only after enabling Firefox to look for userChrome.css as startup (see https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html#aboutconfig):

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution, but Firefox is still hosting the last version 88.0.1, you can always install that and disable updates.

More of a workaround than a real fix.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-firefox?redirectslug=install-older-version-of-firefox&redirectlocale=en-US#w_i-still-want-to-downgrade-where-can-i-get-the-previous-version

Comment: I tried this and initially lost my user profile with passwords and over 1000 bookmarks!