# New Firefox Update Bookmarks Toolbar (Show more bookmarks) | Double Space Problem

Tags: firefox, updates

I updated my firefox to the latest version :
`Version 92.0`
Now in Bookmarks Toolbar (Show more bookmarks) i have a problem about double Space between bookmarks.
There is a thread in stack like this :
[new-firefox-update-menu-bookmark-padding-spacing-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795063/new-firefox-update-menu-bookmark-padding-spacing-fix)
But i could n't find any `userChrome.css` file in fiefox profile folder.
How can i fix double space issue?

---

Try browser.proton.contextmenus.enabled > false (disables Proton UI of context menus)

**Did not work for me.**

---

As you see in the image below spaces are more than usual.

[image]

This is really annoying.
Please guide me to fix this issue without manipulating or creating new rules in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the file (and folder) yourself, and enable setting in about:config to tell Firefox it should apply it. Recycled howto for enabling and easy debugging from https://twitter.com/myfonj/status/1387584962354982912 :

## How to inspect Firefox UI, make changes and persist them across restarts, in 9 steps:

### 1. Enable userChrome.css

Visit about:config, search for '.styles' and toggle `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
to true.

### 2. Enable UI debugging

Open ≡ Menu > More Tools > Web Developer Tools > ⚙ Settings > Advanced and check
(or press F12, then F1)

- [✓] "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes"
- [✓] "Enable remote debugging"

### 3. Obtain location of your Firefox user `<profile folder>`

See path at
about:support#profile-row

### 4. Open Browser Toolbox

Launch ≡ Menu > More Tools > Browser Toolbox
(or  press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+I)

### 5. Allow incoming connection.

### 6. Switch to Style(sheet) Editor.

### 7. Create new style

### 8. Try canonical `* { color: red !important; }`

### 9. Save it as `<profile folder>\chrome\userChrome.css`

### (10.) Done. Now you can close the Toolbox and Firefox without losing your precious tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why did i face that problem?
Is there any better way instead of manipulating firefox css?

Comment: This thread helped me a lot side by side your answer : [New Firefox Update Bookmarks Toolbar (Show more bookmarks) | Double Space Problem](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1350206#answer-1443728)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Mozilla bug about this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1722368

Answer (score 0):

Fixing Menu Double Spacing in FireFox

Introduction

The drop down menus in FireFox have been double spaced for quite some time. This can be quite annoying as it requires more scrolling to see menu contents than is necessary. This document describes how to override this ‘feature’.

[Before and After Menu Spacing][1]

Background

You can blame this on some genius at Mozilla who thought it was a good idea. Up until FireFox 91+ you were provided with a means to override this flash of brilliance. This was done by setting

browser.proton.enabled = false

on the about:config FireFox page

Since FireFox 91+; this no longer works. Evidently the same genius struck again. Now the code below needs to be added the userChrome.css file below the default @namespace line and a parameter needs to be set in the about:config page. More about this in a bit.

---

````
    menupopup > menuitem, menupopup > menu {padding-top: 2px !important; padding-bottom: 2px !important;}
*|*:root {--arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 2px 8px !important;}

```
________________________________________

FYI: References to ‘Chrome’ you will see throughout this document have nothing to do with Google’s Chrome browser.

The following assumes you will be creating a new userChrome.css file and latching it into FireFox. Modifying an existing userChrome.css file should become self-evident once you navigate to your FireFox profile folder. Three basic steps are required.

•   Creating a directory for the userChrome.css file.
•   Creating the userChrome.css file
•   Latching the userChrome.css file into FireFox

Creating a Directory for userChrome.css

The userChrome.css file lives in a directory in your FireFox profile called ‘chrome’ (all lower case). You will need to create this directory if not already there.

In FireFox, click on the hamburger in the upper right corner and open the "Help -> More Troubleshooting Information" page. Then find the button to open your profile folder in the Application Basics Section.

 [Ope Profile Folder][2]

Pressing this button will bring up File Explorer opened to your profile folder .

Create a folder and name it ‘chrome’, all lower case, and navigate into it. Leave the File Explorer open for now.

 [Profile Folder][3]

Creating userChrome.css

If there is not a userChrome.css file already available; you can use the code provided to create one. When copying the code from above; you need to paste into a simple text editor such as NotePad, and save it from there. This will eliminate any unprintable Word formatting characters that may be in the original.

There is a chance your editor will have a hard time navigating to the ‘chrome’ directory you just created. Especially if ‘AppData’ in the path to your ‘chrome’ folder is hidden. Save the text in your editor using “Save File As”, to a file named ‘userChrome.css’ on your desk top. Case is important.

Now drag ‘userChrome.css’ from the desk top to the open ‘chrome’ folder in File Explorer.

Latching userChrome.css into FireFox

Making FireFox aware of the new userChrome requires a preference to be set. In particular, parameter “toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets” needs to be set to “true”.

To do this enter “about:config” in the address bar, press return, and accept the risks.

Be aware messing with the parameters can be like fooling around with the control rods in a nuclear reactor.  One slip up can result in a meltdown. Don’t mess with any of the other parameters unless you know what you are doing.

 [Accept Risk Button][4]

Enter “toolkit.legacy” in the search that comes up and press return.

Now press the double arrow to set this parameter to ‘true’
[setting parameter][5]
 
The parameter is set as soon as you change it. There is no “Save” or “Update” button to press.

You are all set. Sign out of FireFox and back in. (I also reset my machine as a placebo measure.) Display your book marks. They should be single spaced.

Nirvana


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH6Lr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/obBKD.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjJXJ.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnUec.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iap1C.png
````